# Yocto renames packages

Tags: package, debian, rename, yocto

Yocto 2.5 renames my packages

Usually in yocto a package which is build from a recipe has the same name as the recipe itself:
eg: aaa.bb -> aaa123.ipk. aaa123-dev.ipk etc
Why is it for some some recipes the name of the package is the name of library which the bb compiles?

I found the following explanation on: http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2014-August/095965.html

Is there a way to keep the name of the package the same as the name of recipe?

Answer (score 2):

Debian renaming policy is indeed the default. You can override this in your recipe with [DEBIAN_NOAUTONAME](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-DEBIAN_NOAUTONAME) and DEBIANNAME:

```
DEBIAN_NOAUTONAME_my-package-name = "1"
```

You could also remove the "debian" inherit on a distro configuration level to prevent the renaming for all packages but that leads to your distro being quite a bit different from other Yocto based distros... I wouldn't recommend it.